# Application disappeared from Google Play after changing title

Tags: android

I have a weird problem with Google Play.

Recently I have published a game I made for class project. Everything went fine, the game was available after 1 hour after publication.

But yesterday I change game's title in developer console, after some time the game disappeared from store. I can't find it on pc and my phone. Searching by package name also doesn't work.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.project.harbinger

It's been almost 24 hours after I edited title. On developer console everything seems fine (game is listed as "published").

Should I wait more time, or it's something more complicated?

EDIT:

Problem solved. I deleted and then re-published game. 3 hours later the game is available in store again

Comment: is your device have internal space to install and download that app

Comment: Yes, but what does my device has to do with store?

Comment: Have you tried searching by your developer name? It might be the case that now the name is similar to some other game(s), but its rank is so low that you don't see it in search.

Comment: Changing the app title should not be a big deal. I did it yesterday, it was a minor change like changing the app description. Double check that com.project.harbinger is your package name in the dev console. What is the current name of your app?

Comment: have u test that in to another device

Comment: I checked. com.project.harbinger is the package name. When I use my developer name I can't find it either. App is currently name as YASG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes Google a while to re-index your app (the title, description, etc). The whole SEO process in the Google Play Store is tricky and takes a bit of patience.

For example, it took me nearly a month for one of my apps to show up under the exact title, even though many apps only had the first or second base word in the name (my app is called Now Manager). After I had 50+ ratings and 1k+ downloads then it started to show in searches that were the exact title or similar to it (abbreviations of the title, spelling errors, etc).

I've also noticed it can take 24-72 hours for developer reports to come in just to see statistics on ratings and downloads.

Best of luck with your game.

Comment: Great! thanks I was wondering why suddenly all my stat gone down(this include promo-code, installed-stats along with ratings count). I _did_ change the app title :D